# Parse JSON to a tree structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm working on a project that requires a `tableView` list of categorized grocery items. Each category can have *n* depth. The `JSON` response from the API looks like this.

```
"items":[
{
  "id":"5366f8d3e4b0e44dc2d4a6fb",
  "name":"String Cheese"
  "description":"Sargento String Cheese",
  "categorization":[
    [
      "Dairy",
      "Cheese"
    ]
  ]
},
{
  "id":"5366f8d3e4b0e44dc2d1a6fb",
  "name":"Budlight 6-pk"
  "description":"Budlight 12-pk",
  "categorization":[
    [
      "Beverages",
      "Alcohol",
      "Beer"
    ]
  ]
}
]
```

Right now I'm creating Item objects from the item dictionaries and storing them in a mutable array like below.

```
NSArray *itemsArray = [response objectForKey:items];

NSMutableArray *itemsMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSDictionary *itemDict in itemsArray){
    Item *itemObj = [[Item alloc] initWithDictionary:itemDict]
    [itemsMutableArray addObject:itemObj];
}
```

I would like to loop through `itemsMutableArray` and create a tree data structure that has a path from the root to each of the items. Then, I would like to be able to use the tree as a datasource for `tableViews` in each level of category.

Here's what my Item class header looks like.

```
@interface Item : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray  *categorization;

@end
```

...and the implementation

```
#import "Item.h"

@implementation Item

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)objDictionary{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.id = [objDictionary valueForKey:@"id"];
        self.name = [objDictionary valueForKey:@"name"];
        self.description = [objDictionary valueForKey:@"description"];
        self.categorization = [objDictionary valueForKey:@"categorization"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I am not very familiar with tree data structures and recursion. I would greatly appreciate any help on how to approach this. Thanks!

Comment: "create a tree data structure that has a path from the root to each of the items." What do you mean. What do you want to display??

Comment: The parsed JSON (coming out of NSJSONSerialization) already is a "tree data structure" -- an NSArray of NSDictionary objects.  All you're talking about doing is replacing the NSDictionary objects with your own custom Item objects containing the exact same data.  Why?  (And where do you see a need for recursion?)

Comment: (I think in your loop above you meant to use itemsMutableArray where you say `[itemArray addObject:itemObj];`.)

Comment: Do you mean a tree of the category attributes? So Dairy->Cheese Dairy->Milk (Where the two "Dairy" are actually the same node) and Beverage->Alcohol->Beer, Beverage->Alcohol->Wine->Red, Beverage->Soda->Coke (Where again the nodes with the same name are actually  the same node) ?

Comment: (But if you're not content to leave the NSDictionarys alone, the scheme you have -- `initWithDictionary` -- is essentially the way to go.)

Comment: If you want a "tree" that maps "categorization" values to your items, it's a simple matter to scan through your final structure (whatever it is) and fill a dictionary with "categorization"/"item" pairs -- you can reference the same "items" you already have (multiple times as necessary) -- no need for copies.

Comment: @Paulw11 you're right that's exactly what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need simple node tree data structure. How about this way?
Hope this little help.

Header

```
@interface ItemCategory : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) ItemCategory *parent;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *children;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n parent:(ItemCategory *)p;
@end

@interface CategoryTree : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) ItemCategory *root;

-(ItemCategory *)_getChildCategory:(ItemCategory *)category name:(NSString *)name;
-(ItemCategory *)_addChildCategory:(ItemCategory *)category name:(NSString *)name;
-(void)_dumpCategory:(ItemCategory *)category depth:(int)depth;

-(void)dump;
-(ItemCategory *)getCategory:(NSArray *)arr;
-(void)addCategory:(NSArray *)arr;

@end
```

Source

```
@implementation CategoryTree
@synthesize root;

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        root = [[ItemCategory alloc] initWithName:@"root" parent:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

-(ItemCategory *)_getChildCategory:(ItemCategory *)category name:(NSString *)name {
    for (ItemCategory *child in category.children)
        if ([child.name isEqualToString:name])
            return child;

    return nil;
}

-(ItemCategory *)_addChildCategory:(ItemCategory *)category name:(NSString *)name {
    ItemCategory *child = [self _getChildCategory:category name:name];
    if (child)
        return child;
    child = [[ItemCategory alloc] initWithName:name parent:category];
    [category.children addObject:child];

    return child;
}

-(void)_dumpCategory:(ItemCategory *)category depth:(int)depth{
    NSString *parentStr = @"";
    ItemCategory *parent = category.parent;
    while (parent) {
        parentStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", parent.name, parentStr.length > 0 ? @">" : @"", parentStr];
        parent = parent.parent;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@%@%@", parentStr, parentStr.length > 0 ? @">" : @"", category.name);

    for (ItemCategory *child in category.children) {

        [self _dumpCategory:child depth:depth + 1];
    }
}

-(void)dump {
    [self _dumpCategory:root depth:0];
}

-(ItemCategory *)getCategory:(NSArray *)arr {
    ItemCategory *category = root;
    for (NSString *categoryName in arr) {
        category = [self _getChildCategory:category name:categoryName];
        if (!category)
            return nil;
    }
    return category;
}

-(void)addCategory:(NSArray *)arr {
    if ([self getCategory:arr])
        return;

    ItemCategory *category = root;
    for (NSString *categoryName in arr) {
        ItemCategory *childCategory = [self _getChildCategory:category name:categoryName];
        if (!childCategory) {
            childCategory = [self _addChildCategory:category name:categoryName];
        }
        category = childCategory;
    }
}
@end
```

Usage

```
CategoryTree *tree = [[CategoryTree alloc] init];
[tree addCategory:@[@"Dairy", @"Cheese"]];
[tree addCategory:@[@"Dairy", @"Milk"]];
[tree addCategory:@[@"Beverages", @"Alcohol", @"Beer"]];
[tree addCategory:@[@"Beverages", @"Alcohol", @"Wine"]];
[tree addCategory:@[@"Beverages", @"Non-Alcohol", @"Cola"]];
[tree dump];
```

Result

```
root
root>Dairy
root>Dairy>Cheese
root>Dairy>Milk
root>Beverages
root>Beverages>Alcohol
root>Beverages>Alcohol>Beer
root>Beverages>Alcohol>Wine
root>Beverages>Non-Alcohol
root>Beverages>Non-Alcohol>Cola
```

Comment: where is the implemention of ItemCategory

Answer (score 0):

well I have found a way to implement what you need. I do not know how optimised it is since i do not how many items you'll be receiving . The implementation is given below.

You need to start with adding this dictionary in `Item.h @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *catTree;`

Next do this to get the tree

```
[itemsMutableArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Item *itm, NSUInteger i,BOOL *stop){
        itm.catTree = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSString *dairy = @"",*beverage = @"";
        for (NSArray *catArray in itm.categorization) {
            /*
                Everything below is written assuming the format of the JSON will be "as-is"
             */

            if ([catArray containsObject:@"Dairy"]) {
                //Take everything except Dairy
                NSArray *stripedArray = [catArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != \"Dairy\""]];
                int i = 0;
                //Loop through the array to get any sub categories.
                while (i < stripedArray.count) {
                    dairy = [dairy stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:(i == stripedArray.count-1)?@"%@ ":@"%@->",stripedArray[i]]]; //Space at the end to account for similar entry in the same category for e.g two dairy products.
                    i++;
                }
            } else  if ([catArray containsObject:@"Beverages"]) {
                NSArray *stripedArray = [catArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != \"Beverages\""]];
                int i = 0;
                while (i < stripedArray.count) {
                    beverage = [beverage stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:(i == stripedArray.count-1)?@"%@ ":@"%@->",stripedArray[i]]];
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }


        //Set the category tree for every item using a dictionary
        [itm.catTree setValue:dairy forKey:@"Dairy"];
        [itm.catTree setValue:beverage forKey:@"Beverage"];

        NSLog(@"%@",itm.catTree);
    }];
```

the above code gives the following output for your json

```
{
    Beverage = "";
    Dairy = "Cheese ";
}
{
    Beverage = "Alcohol->Beer ";
    Dairy = "";
}
```

For multiple beverages

```
{
   Beverage = "Alcohol->Beer Alcohol->Wine->Red Soda->Coke ";
   Dairy = "";
}
```

Hope this helps.